How can I replace my minecraft multiplayer playerdata with my survival playerdata?
So, I was playing on a minecraft multiplayer server with some friends for a few weeks, after that they stopped playing so we stopped paying for the server, I wanted to continue playing on my own, when I downloaded the world instead of having all my items I appeared as a new player, I tried to edit the player data in multiple ways but it overwrote itself all the time, I suspect it's because the server we were playing on was non-premium and I was logging in with my premium account so the UUID is not the same, I tried renaming, copying and pasting the files from my multiplayer data to singleplayer but it keeps overwriting every time I log into the game.

I believe your question is similar to this one: Transfer world from multiplayer to singleplayer and continue with the right progress
Basically you'll need to remove your player file from level.dat.

Hi, if you think the linked q&a solve the OP's problem, you can flag it as a duplicate. If you're answering questions, it's better to actually give a complete answer, rather than "see here, it involves this".
